# How to left align an image in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the image to appear on the left with content on the right.

desired output would be:

[image: image on the left]

my images on the below appear above the content.  I've tried a number of things with the `flex-direction` but just can't get the image to appear on the left.

here's my cut down code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```css
<style>html {
  background: #f5f7f8;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.band {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .band {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .item-1 {
    grid-column: 1/ span 2;
  }
  .item-1 h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) {
  .band {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}


/* card */

.card {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.card:hover {
  top: -2px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card article {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card .thumb {
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.card p {
  flex: 1;
  /* make p grow to fill available space*/
  line-height: 1.4;
}


/* typography */

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.card span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="support-grid"></div>

<div class="band">

  <div class="item-4">
    <a href="#" class="card">

      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-5">
    <a href="#" class="card">

      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-6">
    <a href="#" class="card">

      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>

      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-7">
    <a href="#" class="card">


      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>

      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `flex-direction: column;` to `flex-direction: row;` on `card`. Then you just have to define a `width` for `thumb` because you are using it as a background image. So I set `width: 100%;` to `thumb`.

```css
html {
  background: #f5f7f8;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.band {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .band {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .item-1 {
    grid-column: 1/ span 2;
  }
  .item-1 h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 850px) {
  .band {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}


/* card */

.card {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.card:hover {
  top: -2px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card article {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card .thumb {
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.card p {
  flex: 1;
  /* make p grow to fill available space*/
  line-height: 1.4;
}


/* typography */

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.card span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
}

.thumb {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="support-grid"></div>
<div class="band">
  <div class="item-4">
    <a href="#" class="card">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-5">
    <a href="#" class="card">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-6">
    <a href="#" class="card">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-7">
    <a href="#" class="card">
      <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg);"></div>
      <article>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <span>content</span>
      </article>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by focusing on these two areas:

1. In your code, the flex container is set to `flex-direction: column`. This makes your image and the article (i.e., the flex items) stack vertically. Remove this `column` setting so that the items can line up in a row (which is the default setting).
2. The flex container will work better if you render the item with HTML (using the `img` tag) as opposed to CSS (using the `background-image` property). It will work *even better* if you wrap the `img` in a `figure`, `div` or other HTML element, as images seem to be problematic for some browsers when they're flex items. The common solution is to make the wrapper a flex item.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
}

div {
  width: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.card article {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="card">
  <div>
    <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financia-positive-pension-happiness-money-saving-retirement-financial-118207382.jpg">
  </div>
  <article>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p></p>
    <span>content</span>
  </article>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `.card` class flex-direction to this:

```
.card {
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

and adding: `flex: 1 0 1%; width:1%;` to `article` and `.thumb` should get you started.